# how to get number of selected vertex and the number of total vertex with python?

Tags: scripting

how to get number of selected vertex and the number of total vertex with python?
and how can I select an object by its name and make it the active?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have multiple questions there:

```
import bpy
import bmesh


obj = bpy.context.active_object
if bpy.context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    verts = [ v.index for v in bm.verts if v.select ]
else:
    verts = [ v.index for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select ]

print(verts)
print(len(obj.data.vertices))
```

and for the second question:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[name]
# fix shortcoming identified by Omar :
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.select = ( obj == bpy.context.scene.objects.active)
```

Comment: thanks,the 1st one work fine but the 2nd one is not working well,I want it to select the object only but I find that it select 2 objects the one that was active and the one I select by the script